# Saving search POST variables in MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

I am developing a site where users choose their city (from a long list), an activity (again a long list) and then a level of expertise. After that, the site shows them local events based upon their choices. I have over 100 POST variables (and more being added). How can this be done in MySQL?

Comment: Have you thought about using a [database library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library) or a [framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com)?

Comment: You should probably come up with a complete specification before doing something like this. If you have a good idea about how these options relate, and how new ones would fit in, a good design pattern would allow you to add in new ones with minimal amount of work. If you already have a full spec, then my advice would be something like a one to many relation between a user and previously selected options.

Comment: This is really more of a design/architecture question, and as such it's off-topic for the site.

Comment: Everytime for users? and the easiest way? is sounds contradictory i think.

Answer (score 0):

You only have a few variables (city, activity, expertise). Use a session.

Here is a link to sessions in PHP  ([sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php))

Comment: Thanks everyone! I discovered the PHP SERVER and PHP SELF functions which will do the trick with MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have the right idea. create a table and store each variable you would like to save.

post whatever variables from whatever scripting language of your choice, and the database statement would look something like this:

```
'INSERT INTO `your_table_name` (`field_1`,`field_2`) VALUES ('$post1','$post2');
```

you can add more fields as your information grows.  That would be the best way to start getting into mysql. Of course this answer is the simplest solution.  I recommend you read up on all fun and much more complex things you can do with mysql.

More efficiently I would do it like this:

categorize / classify your post variables and create multiple tables grouping similar things or data from a specific page.  Create an auto increment primary id for your rows on the master table of the group, and then join your tables as needed. That's a little more advanced, so I suggest you add your few fields that you currently are using to a table now, and when you need to start adding more, looking these topics:

Normalization:
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Primary Keys, Joins, Stored Procedures, and the list goes on.